# Render radio buttons based on arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, radio-button

I am developing an online school assessment. In it I receive some questions and each question has several options for selection.

I need to show the options as Radio Buttons, allowing the user to select 1 option per question.

My Radio Button component is this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, InputHTMLAttributes } from 'react';
import { useField } from '@unform/core';
interface Props extends InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
  name: string;
  options: {
    id: number;
    option: string;
  }[];
}
export default function RadioInput({ name, options, ...rest }: Props) {
  console.log(options);

  const inputRefs = useRef<HTMLInputElement[]>([]);
  const { fieldName, registerField, defaultValue = '' } = useField(name);
  useEffect(() => {
    registerField({
      name: fieldName,
      ref: inputRefs.current,
      getValue: (refs: HTMLInputElement[]) => {
        return refs.find(ref => ref.checked)?.value || '';
      },
      setValue: (refs: HTMLInputElement[], id: string) => {
        const inputRef = refs.find(ref => ref.id === id);
        if (inputRef) inputRef.checked = true;
      },
      clearValue: (refs: HTMLInputElement[]) => {
        const inputRef = refs.find(ref => ref.checked === true);
        if (inputRef) inputRef.checked = false;
      },
    });
  }, [defaultValue, fieldName, registerField]);
  return (
    <>
      {options.map(option => (
        <label htmlFor={String(option.id)} key={option.id}>
          <input
            ref={ref => inputRefs.current.push(ref as HTMLInputElement)}
            type="radio"
            name={name}
            defaultChecked={defaultValue.includes(option.id)}
            value={option.option}
            {...rest}
          />
          {option.option}
        </label>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

Options consist of several arrays with the options of the questions, as shown in the image below:
[image: options return]

For a moment the component is rendered correctly on the screen, however, after a few seconds I get the following error:
[image]

Something is wrong with the options interface.

The way I'm doing it is (complete code can be found at [GIST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVdaN.png)):

```
{options.map(option => (
  <label htmlFor={String(option.id)} key={option.id}>
    <input
      ref={ref => inputRefs.current.push(ref as HTMLInputElement)}
      type="radio"
      name={name}
      defaultChecked={defaultValue.includes(option.id)}
      value={option.option}
      {...rest}
    />
    {option.option}
  </label>
))}
```

Code where I call the radio button component and pass the options and name is in this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback, useRef } from 'react';
import { useRouteMatch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { FormHandles } from '@unform/core';
import { Form } from '@unform/web';

import api from '../../../services/api';
import { useToast } from '../../../hooks/toast';

import Menu from '../../../components/Menu';
import Footer from '../../../components/Footer';
import HeaderInfo from '../../../components/HeaderInfo/HeaderInfoMoreItems';
import NormalButton from '../../../components/NormalButton';
import RadioInput from '../../../components/RadioButton';

import { Container } from './styles';

interface OptionsData{
  id: number;
  option: string;
}

interface ExamData {
  id: number;
  question: string;
  essay_question: boolean;
  options: OptionsData;
}

interface ModuleIdParams {
  exam_id: string;
  module_id: string;
  course_id: string;
}

const ExamQuestions: React.FC = () => {
  const [exam, setExam] = useState<ExamData[]>([]);
  const [loadingExam, setLoadingExam] = useState(false);

  const formRef = useRef<FormHandles>(null);

  console.log(exam);

  const { addToast } = useToast();
  const { params } = useRouteMatch<ModuleIdParams>();

  const course_info = {
    course_id: params.course_id,
    module_id: params.module_id,
  };

  const getExam = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      setLoadingExam(true);
      await api
        .get(`/questions/exam/${params.exam_id}`)
        .then(response => {
          setExam(response.data);
        });

      setLoadingExam(false);
    } catch (err) {
      setLoadingExam(true);
      addToast({
        type: 'error',
        title:
          'Ocorreu um erro ao carregar, verifique sua conexão com a internet.',
      });
      setLoadingExam(false);
    }
  }, [addToast, params.exam_id]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getExam();
  }, [getExam]);

  const handleSubmit = useCallback(async (data) => {
    console.log("asdads");
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Menu />
      <HeaderInfo course_info={course_info} />
      <Container>
        <h6>
          Avaliação
        </h6>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

        <div>
          <Form
            name="exam"
            ref={formRef}
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
          >
            <ol>
            {exam.map(e => (
              <li key={e.id} >
                <p>{e.question}</p>
                <RadioInput name={String(e.id)} options={e.options} />
              </li>
            ))}

            </ol>
            <NormalButton type="submit">Enviar</NormalButton>
          </Form>
        </div>
      </Container>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

export default ExamQuestions;
```

Comment: Can you include the code rendering the `RadioInput` component?

Comment: It's on the bottom line of the question.

Comment: Can you please add the code to the question? I've updated my answer.

Comment: Edited! I changed the form to pass the props options for the component, that way it is rendered momentarily on the screen, however, right after I get the image error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code in the [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/fredarend/8c410c4b1e2b56c6dd9fe99814349c07#file-questions-tsx-L100) you shared:

```
<RadioInput name={String(e.id)} options={[e.options]} />
```

The `RadioInput` component expects an array (which `e.options` already is) but you're passing a nested array. It should instead be

```
<RadioInput name={String(e.id)} options={e.options} />
```

The other issue is that in the `ExamData` interface, `options` should be declared as an array of `OptionsData` - `OptionsData[]`.

```
interface ExamData {
  id: number;
  options: OptionsData[];
}
```

Comment: Sorry Arun.

The question I asked you earlier helped me to solve. I will create the new one in another topic, considering that it is a different problem.

Comment: @Fred No worries. I updated my answer to address the type issue as well.